# Where does AbstractQueuedSynchronizer changes its head reference in exclusive mode

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm research the source code of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer class, when I read the code of `acquireQueued` method:

```java
    final boolean acquireQueued(final Node node, int arg) {
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            boolean interrupted = false;
            for (;;) {
                final Node p = node.predecessor();
                if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                    setHead(node);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    failed = false;
                    return interrupted;
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                    interrupted = true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }
```

the statement `final Node p = node.predecessor();` means get present node's prev node `p`. the next if statement try to compare the `p` node and the `head` node.

My doubt is how is the `head` node changed so that code can enter the if statement, and which code block is the change happened

It seems that I can't find the code block in `shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire`/`parkAndCheckInterrupt`/`release`/`unparkSuccessor` method

Answer (score 0):

1. Obviously, when the second node is woken up and tryAcquire success,  it becomes the head node. 
   `setHead(node);`
   Then when the third node is awakened, the head node changes.
2. Entering the if statement does not necessarily mean that the head has changed. 
   If the previous node of this node is canceled, then this node may act as the back node of the head node. see detail in `shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire` method